# Fancybox not working in Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am a Foundation 6 beginner.

I made a website responsive with Foundation 6. 
Fancybox via Processwire was working smoothly.
Now I have implemented F6, and theres no more fancybox....The photos open in a new page.

http://olikehrli.ch/galerie/

Does anybody have a suggestion what the cause could be? It is exactly the same as it was before, but now with the framework....it HAS to be something with F6.

Thanks for any help

Jakob

**These are the links for Fancybox in the Header**

```
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $config->urls->templates?>source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $config->urls->templates?>source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $config->urls->templates?>source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $config->urls->templates?>source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $config->urls->templates?>source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $config->urls->templates?>source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $config->urls->te
```

**The link for fancybox in the PHP**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-7 medium-8 medium-push-1 columns" id="bg" >


                <!--        BILDERGALLERIE MIT PHP      -->

        <? echo $page->seitenname; ?>

        </br>
        </br>
        </br>


            <?php

        foreach($page->bildergalerie as $image) {
        $thumbnail = $image->size(180,180);
        echo "<a href='{$image->url}'  class='fancybox' rel='group' title='{$thumbnail->description}'><img src='{$thumbnail->url}' alt='{$thumbnail->description}'  ></a>";
        }

        ?>          

    </div>



        <!-- <div class="sidebar"> -->
 <div class="small-12 large-5 medium-4  columns" id="bg" >

            <? echo $page->sidebar; ?>

    </div>  


</div>
```

**This is at the bottom of the html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fancybox").fancybox();
   });
</script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why script lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js not found?

Comment: Open the web console you will see "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function"

Comment: Right! What do I have to do with the Uncaught Type Error?